Make textbox mandatory and output message
thanks for the wonderful help given since I joined. In fairness I googled till my fingers got sore, but did not find what I was searching for, so here I am. I am new to windows forms using PowerShell and I am trying to make a textbox mandatory, but no luck. In addition, I would like if ignored some kind of message alerts the user to fill the field. All my searches have returned C# or html or other languages, or using PowerShell Studio by Sapien. Everything else in the function works as expected, just need to make the text box mandatory. Anyway, here is my code:
#region Prereqs
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
#end region Prereqs

Add-type -AssemblyName system.windows.forms
#define object variables
$formobject = [System.Windows.forms.form] #this sets the variable so no need to keep tying system.windows.forms.form
$lblobjpuid = [System.Windows.Forms.Label]
$TextobjOutput = [System.Windows.Forms.textbox]
$textboxobjInst = [System.Windows.Forms.textbox]
$TxtboxObjPUID = [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox]
$TxtboxObjPath = [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox]
$btnobjTrellix = [System.Windows.Forms.Button]
$btnobjMECM = [System.Windows.Forms.Button]
$btnobjGPO= [System.Windows.Forms.Button]
$btnobjDisableFW = [System.Windows.Forms.Button]
$btnobjVerifyTrellix = [System.Windows.Forms.Button]
$btnobjShowNIC = [System.Windows.Forms.Button]
$btnobjAppVerify = [System.Windows.Forms.Button]
$btnobjclear = [System.Windows.Forms.Button]
$btnobjExit = [System.Windows.Forms.Button]


#build main form
$LSForm=New-object $formobject
$LSForm.clientsize= '700,450' #set the height and width
$LSForm.text ='Post Lift & Shift Actions'
$LSForm.backcolor='white'
$DefaultFont='Verdana,10'
$LSForm.Font=$DefaultFont

#build PUID label object
$lblPUID=new-object $lblobjpuid
$lblPUID.Location=New-Object system.drawing.point(10,10)
$lblPUID.Text="Enter your PUID"
$lblPUID.AutoSize=$true

<#build Output label object
$LabelOutPut=new-object $lblobjOutput
$LabelOutPut.Location=New-Object system.drawing.point(10,200)
$LabelOutPut.AutoSize=$true
$LabelOutPut.MaximumSize.Width='100'
#>
#build output textbox object
$TxtBoxOutput=New-object $TextobjOutput
$TxtBoxOutput.Multiline=$true
$TxtBoxOutput.WordWrap=$true
$TxtBoxOutput.ReadOnly=$true
$TxtBoxOutput.Autosize=$true
$TxtBoxOutput.Size=[drawing.size]::new(250,200)
$TxtBoxOutput.text=''
$TxtBoxOutput.Location=New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,200)
$TxtBoxOutput.BackColor="White"
$TxtBoxOutput.font = "verdana,10"


#build PUID textbox object
$PUIDTextbox=new-object $TxtboxObjPUID
$PUIDTextbox.Location=new-object System.Drawing.Point (130,10)

#build Trellix button object
$BTNTrellix=new-object $btnobjTrellix
$BTNTrellix.Text='Install Trellix for BPUS'
$BTNTrellix.AutoSize=$true
$BTNTrellix.Location=New-Object system.drawing.point(10,120)
$BTNTrellix.ForeColor='black'
$BTNTrellix.BackColor='#45edea'
$BTNTrellix.font=$DefaultFont

#build MECM install button object
$BTNMECM=new-object $btnobjMECM
$BTNMECM.Text='Install BPUS MECM Agent'
$BTNMECM.AutoSize=$true
$BTNMECM.Location=New-Object system.drawing.point(10,80)
$BTNMECM.ForeColor='black'
$BTNMECM.BackColor='#45edea'
$BTNMECM.Font=$DefaultFont

#build query GPO button object
$BTNGPO=new-object $btnobjGPO
$BTNGPO.Text='Pull GPO Info'
$BTNGPO.AutoSize=$true
$BTNGPO.Location=New-Object system.drawing.point(205,80)
$BTNGPO.ForeColor='black'
$BTNGPO.BackColor='#45edea'
$BTNGPO.Font=$DefaultFont

#build verify Apps button object
$BTNVERIFYAPP=new-object $btnobjAppVerify
$BTNVERIFYAPP.Text='Verify Legacy Apps Removed'
$BTNVERIFYAPP.AutoSize=$true
$BTNVERIFYAPP.Location=New-Object system.drawing.point(10,40)
$BTNVERIFYAPP.ForeColor='white'
$BTNVERIFYAPP.BackColor='RED'
$BTNVERIFYAPP.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Verdana",10,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold) 

#build verify Show NICs button object
$BTNSHOWNIC=new-object $btnobjShowNIC
$BTNSHOWNIC.Text='Show NICs'
$BTNSHOWNIC.AutoSize=$true
$BTNSHOWNIC.Location=New-Object system.drawing.point(185,120)
$BTNSHOWNIC.ForeColor='black'
$BTNSHOWNIC.BackColor='#45edea'
$BTNSHOWNIC.Font=$DefaultFont

#build verify Disable Firewall button object
$BTNDISFW=new-object $btnobjDisableFW
$BTNDISFW.Text='Disable/Show Firewall'
$BTNDISFW.AutoSize=$true
$BTNDISFW.Location=New-Object system.drawing.point(10,160)
$BTNDISFW.ForeColor='black'
$BTNDISFW.BackColor='#45edea'
$BTNDISFW.Font=$DefaultFont


#build verify Trellix button object
$BTNVERIFYTRELLIX=new-object $btnobjVerifyTrellix
$BTNVERIFYTRELLIX.Text='Verify Trellix Agent'
$BTNVERIFYTRELLIX.AutoSize=$true
$BTNVERIFYTRELLIX.Location=New-Object system.drawing.point(185,160)
$BTNVERIFYTRELLIX.ForeColor='black'
$BTNVERIFYTRELLIX.BackColor='#45edea'
$BTNVERIFYTRELLIX.Font=$DefaultFont



#build clear all button object
$Btnclear=new-object $btnobjclear
$Btnclear.Text='Clear all'
$Btnclear.AutoSize=$true
$Btnclear.Location=New-Object system.drawing.point(300,400)
$Btnclear.ForeColor='black'
$Btnclear.BackColor='Yellow'
$Btnclear.Font=$DefaultFont
$BTNclear.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Verdana",10,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold) 

#build exit button object
$Btnx=new-object $btnobjExit
$Btnx.Text='E&xit'
$Btnx.AutoSize=$true
$Btnx.Location=New-Object system.drawing.point(400,400)
$Btnx.ForeColor='black'
$Btnx.BackColor='Green'
$btnx.Font='verdana,10'
$Btnx.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Verdana",10,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold) 

#build instruction textbox object
$Textboxinst=New-object $textboxobjInst
$Textboxinst.Multiline=$true
$Textboxinst.WordWrap=$true
$Textboxinst.ReadOnly=$true
$Textboxinst.Autosize=$true
$Textboxinst.Size=[drawing.size]::new(300,350)
$Textboxinst.text="This Post Lift & Shift Actions applet will allow you to perform various tasks as per the button names. Press click the Verify Apps button FIRST to confirm ALL legacy apps are removed. The Show NIC button shows the status of the NIC. Click Verify Trellix Agent button and make sure the 'UserProperty 2' field matches the zone. The Disable/Show Firewall button will disable the firewall if it is enabled, then show the status, make sure it shows 'False'. The GPO button displays the policies in a gridview, be patient while it loads. The Trellix and MECM buttons installs for BPUS ONLY. DO NOT USE THOSE FOR ANY OTHER ZONES!"
$Textboxinst.Location=New-Object System.Drawing.Point(350,10)
$Textboxinst.BackColor="White"
$Textboxinst.font = "verdana,10"



#build functions for the buttons to perform
Function Verify_Trellix{

 $AgentStatus = CMD /C "C:\Program Files\McAfee\Agent\cmdagent.exe" "-x" | Select-String -Pattern 'Userproperty2:'
 #$TxtBoxOutput.Text=$AgentStatus
 
$TxtBoxOutput.Text = $AgentStatus -join "`r`n"  # Join the lines with carriage return and newline
 }

Function Show_NICs{
#Get-NetIPAddress |Out-GridView
$NIC_Status = Get-NetAdapter * | Select-Object -Property "Name", "Status" | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name + ": " + $_.Status
}
$TxtBoxOutput.Text = $NIC_Status -join "`r`n"  # Join the lines with carriage return and newline
}

#Show GPO Information
Function Show_GPO{
gpresult /scope computer /z |Out-GridView |Format-Table -AutoSize
}
#Disable and show firewall status
Function FireWall {
$FWStatus = (Get-NetFirewallProfile).Enabled 
if($FWStatus -eq "True"){
Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Private,Public -Enabled False -Verbose 
}
Get-NetFirewallProfile | Select-Object -Property "Name", "Enabled" | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name + ": " + $_.Enabled
}
$TxtBoxOutput.Text=$FWStatus -join "`r`n" 
}
#Install BPUS MECM Agent
Function Install_MECM {
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
start-process -FilePath "$ScriptPath\Source_Files\Client\ccmsetup.exe" -ArgumentList 'SMSSITECODE=EAM','SMSMP=HTTPS://BPUS001INVP003.BP-US.LOCAL','DNSSUFFIX=bp-us.local', 'SMSCACHESIZE=10', 'SMSCACHEFLAGS=PERCENTDISKSPACE', '/NOSERVICE','/UsePKICert','/NoCRLCheck','/source:$ScriptPath\Source_Files\Client'
}

Function Verify_Apps{
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$PUID
    )
$PUID=$PUIDTextbox.Text
$RegKey = 'Lift&Shift'
$registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Eurofins\Lift&Shift";
If ( !(Test-Path $registryPath) ) { New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force; };
New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name  $RegKey -Value "Lift&shift performed by:$PUID" -PropertyType String –Force;
get-package | Out-GridView
}

#Install Trellix
Function Install_Trellix {
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
& $scriptPath\Source_Files\Trellix\Install_ALL.ps1
}

#clear all text fields
Function ClearTxtBoxes {
$PUIDTextbox.Text = ""
}



##Assign functions to the button
$BTNVERIFYTRELLIX.Add_Click({Verify_Trellix})
$Btnclear.Add_Click({ClearTxtBoxes})
$BTNMECM.Add_Click({Install_MECM})
$Btnx.Add_Click({
$LSForm.FormClosing;$LSForm.Close()
})
$BTNSHOWNIC.Add_Click({Show_NICs})
$BTNGPO.Add_Click({Show_GPO})
$BTNDISFW.Add_Click({FireWall})
$BTNVERIFYAPP.Add_Click({Verify_Apps})
$BTNTrellix.Add_Click({Install_Trellix})






#create an array to accept all the controls you want to appear on the form
#$NICForm.Controls.AddRange(@($lbltitle, $BTNTrellix, $lbltitle1, $lbltitle2, $lbltitle3, $TxtboxOldName, $TxtboxNewName, $TxtboxIPAdd, $BtnRenameNIC, $BtnDisable, $BtnIPAdd, $btnclear, $BTNMECM, $Textboxinst, $BTNx))
$LSForm.Controls.AddRange(@($TxtBoxOutput,$BTNTrellix, $btnclear, $lblPUID, $BTNMECM, $Textboxinst, $BTNx, $BTNMECM, $PUIDTextbox, $BTNGPO, $BTNVERIFYAPP, $BTNSHOWNIC, $BTNDISFW, $BTNVERIFYTRELLIX))

$LSForm.showdialog() #displays the form
$LSForm.dispose() #cleans up form

I only added the parameters in an effort to make the box mandatory, but all it did was prompt and await input in the console. The reg key does get populated based on the input to the textbox, so that works. That function is assigned to a button click. I thought by adding the parameter, if they skipped the textbox and clicked the button it would at least error out. But again, all that happened was the wait in the console for the input, then once I typed something and pressed enter, it allowed entry to the form. Thanks in advance

The code provided is irrelevant to the question being asked. You should add the WinForms code instead of this function

Oh sorry, let me edit and add the code

Making a parameter of PowerShell function Mandatory has no effect for a WinForm App other than hanging it, because invoking the function with no arguments would await for user input.
There are different ways of having the user provide input to the text box but WinForms does not provide any concept of "mandatory". One of the ways could be for example, disabling all buttons that must have an input in the text box and only enabling them after said text box has been populated. For this, you can use the .TextChanged Event, in your event handler the logic would be, if the .Text property is null or empty space, disable all buttons that should be considered mandatory, else, enable them.
A simple example of how the logic looks like:
# this code goes right after `$LSForm.Controls.AddRange...`

# add all buttons considered mandatory here
$mandatoryButtons = @(
    $BTNTrellix
    $BTNMECM
    $BTNGPO
    $BTNSHOWNIC
    # and so on, add all buttons here
)

# all mandatory buttons should start in disabled state because the
# PUID textbox is empty when the form loads
$mandatoryButtons | ForEach-Object { $_.Enabled = $false }

$PUIDTextbox.Add_TextChanged({
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($this.Text)) {
        $mandatoryButtons | ForEach-Object { $_.Enabled = $false }
        return
    }
    $mandatoryButtons | ForEach-Object { $_.Enabled = $true }
})

$LSForm.ShowDialog()



Man, tell me where to send you beer fund you, no kidding. This is even better than I expected. I am also going to add a code to query AD for the PUID in case someone tries to get slick and some random code thinking they can fake the process. Thanks so much.

Sorry to bother, but can I ask one last favor please? For the If statement that controls the button becoming active, can you add an "and" to that so that the PUIDTextbox AND the $TxtBoxOutput needs to populate before the other buttons are enabled. This way if they type random info, the result won't come back to populate UNLESS they input the correct PUID. Thanks

Tried this, but no bueno
$TxtboxInput.Add_TextChanged({
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($this.Text -and $LabelDisp.Text.Length -igt 0)) {
$mandatoryButtons | ForEach-Object { $.Enabled = $false }
return
}
$mandatoryButtons | ForEach-Object { $.Enabled = $true }
})

this belongs to a new question @user330183. Here I'm answering the question initially asked

Oh, apologies, I will ask a new question
